# Phusion passenger installation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, passenger

Following [installation guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/bionic/) for 18.04 worked fine, however it seems it's still not possible to install phusion passenger on 20.04.

If I try to use bionic package - it is incompatible with new nginx version. And it seems there is no dedicated focal package yet. Or is it?

Answer (score 1):

We need to wait for the next release according to this: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2263#issuecomment-622099744